# Extract text not included in a parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This select the string inside the parenthesis,

```
$text = 'ignore everything except this (text)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);


echo $match[1] . ' /parentheses';
```

How can I echo the text that is not inside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$text = 'ignore everything except this (text)';
preg_match('/(.*)\((.*?)\)/', $text, $match);

echo "in parenthesis: " . $match[2] . "\n";
echo "outside parenthesis: " . $match[1] . "\n";
```

Needless to say it assumes a single set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_match('^(*.?)\((*.?)\)(*.?)$', $text, $match);
echo $match[0] . $match[2];
```

Assuming only one set of parenthesis.